# What do 'drive' and 'hard' refer to in 'drive a hard bargain'?

Tags: etymology, verbs, idioms

If I have to say that "this person(X) does very good bargaining" in a more refined way, I should ideally write "X **drives a hard bargain**". (I saw it in a book). I know that I have to use 'bargain' word here but now I wonder how they came up with '**drive**' and '**hard**'. Is this something which instinctively comes to their mind?

Comment: I've always taken "drive" to be in the sense of someone driving a stake into the ground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [drive a hard bargain](http://rollsoffthetongue.tumblr.com/post/99107159855/drive-a-hard-bargain-origin-mid-19th-century), *drive* seems to refer to *drive a vehicle* used metaphorically meaning to conduct a negotiation.  *Hard* refers to the strong, determined way in which the deal is carried out.

> - Origin: Mid-19th Century, American English. Even though ***“drive” sounds like it could be a 20th Century word having to do with automobiles, the word goes back to Old English and German before that, meaning to pursue, hunt, push from behind.*** And of course, humans have been driving cattle and other domestic animals for thousands of years. So it’s easy to see why the word was chosen in regard to vehicles. From there it’s an simple metaphoric leap to negotiating and bargaining.
> - Usage:  Informal, spoken, general, American and British English
>   Idiomatic Meaning: ***To be a strong negotiator and deal maker***, succeeding in gaining the advantage over an adversary in a contract or a buying/selling/trading situation.
> - Literal Meaning: To operate and control the direction and speed of a vehicle made of a hard material as opposed to a soft material
> - Sample sentence: You “drove such a hard bargain” that I feel compelled to sign the contract.

(rollsoffthetongue.tumblr.com)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, *drive* is being used in the sense of "forcing into existence through vigorous effort" (see [definition 10 in Am Heritage](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=drive)), a meaning which probably follows from the more common use of *drive* to mean "force to do something" (e.g. bad luck may *drive someone to drink*).

The usage of *hard* is meant to indicate the effort involved, and is used in the sense of difficulty ("hard" = "difficult").  The more difficult it is to make a bargain, the more effort is involved in making it.

Because the person who drives the bargain is the one expending the effort, there is an implication that "driving a hard bargain" means spending a lot of time/effort on achieving a bargain which is beneficial to the person driving the bargain.

There's actually a slight connotative difference between someone being "good at bargaining" and someone "driving a hard bargain".  The former implies that the skilled bargainer does not necessarily spend much effort at it but achieves a good outcome nonetheless, and describes someone's skill in general as opposed to a particular occasion.  The latter implies much effort being expended in the successful pursuit of a particular bargain.

Answer (score -1):

In 17th and 18th Century Cumberland, England, it is documented that teams of 4-6 miners would negotiate a price in advance for hand-cutting their way through a specified length of rock, while digging a mine.  That price became fixed and the task had to be completed.  It was known as the 'bargain'.  The act of digging the new section of tunnel - again documented - was known as 'driving'.  And the solidity of the material to be dug through naturally varied in ways that could not be accurately predicted, and if it was solid rock and thus hard work to dig through, it was known as a hard bargain... driving a hard bargain. (Submitted by Eddie Wren)

Comment: Please provide the documentation you refer to.  And, are you referring to coal mining, which, at least by the 20th century, was differentiated from hard rock mining.